# Precompile part of the web application in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pre-compilation

Is it possible to precompile some of .cshtml, .ascx, .aspx files in my web application?
My website is built with CMS(Umbraco) and I do not want to include all umbraco files into project and precompile it. I would like to precompile only files that were created by me...

Comment: It seems possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio. Sorry I don't have time for a full-fledged answer, but hopefully this link is somewhat helpful.

Comment: @BartoszKP thanks for answer. But your link follows to .net CORE documentation but I would like to do itn in old .net..

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't look close enough.